# Jsoup html parsing items under span

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to parse items using Jsoup on Java.
When i open the source code for the website i'm trying to read

```
    <ul class="myptab typ3">
        <li><span class="active"><a href="#;" id="ONE_TO_ONE">1+1</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#;" id="TWO_TO_ONE">2+1</a></span></li>
    </ul>


    <h5 class="invisible" >1+1 itemlist</h5>
    <div class="tblwrap mt50">
        <ul class="prod_list">
        </ul>
        <div class="paging">
        </div>
    </div>

    <h5 class="invisible">2+1 itemlist</h5>
    <div class="tblwrap mt50">
        <ul class="prod_list">

        </ul>
        <div class="paging">
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this source code the  for either 1+1 section or 2+1 section is listed but when i use inspect to see the source code on the 1+1 section item,

```
    <h5 class="invisible">1+1 itemlist</h5>
    <div class="tblwrap mt50"> ==$0
    <ul class="prod_list">
      <li>
        <div class="prod_box">
          <p class="img"></p>
          <p class="title">mangomilk_pet_300ML</p>
      </li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
```

it pops up like that.
so I'd like to select p.title and p.img from the hidden span items in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the content is built dynamically by javascript. In this case **jsoup** is not enough. You can try to use **jBrowserDriver** which is able to retrieve completed DOM (with rendered javascript part).

Example code:

```
// Represents result item
public class ProductBox {
    private final String image;
    private final String title;

    public ProductBox(String image, String title) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getImage() { return image; }
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
}


// Method responsible for parsing a page
public void processPage(String url) {
    JBrowserDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings
            .builder()
            .timezone(Timezone.AMERICA_NEWYORK)
            .userAgent(UserAgent.CHROME)
            .build());

    driver.get(url);
    String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
    driver.quit();

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(pageSource);
    Elements prodBoxes = doc.select("ul.prod_list div.prod_box");
    List<ProductBox> products = prodBoxes.stream()
            .map(e -> new ProductBox(e.select("p.img").text(), e.select("p.title").text()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    products.forEach(e -> System.out.printf("%s - %s\n", e.getImage(), e.getTitle()));
}
```